# How to change the measurement system with MKMap in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, units-of-measurement

I know, this question is very simple, and so should the answer. However, for whatever reason, I just cannot find an answer on the Internet. I would like to change the map scale to the metric system in my app, but I simply can't find a way to do so. Funny enough, I'm pretty sure that I've done it before when I was playing with it.

Anyway, thank you so much in advance! I know this is a dumb question, but I've been searching for it for more than an hour now and still have no luck.

Comment: Distances from the location manager are reported in meters already. What measurements are you referring to?

Comment: I'd like to change the units of the map scale, i.e., the ruler that shows up when you set mapView.showsScale to true

Comment: Interesting question. I don't see a setting for that after a quick search. I bet it is based on the user's locale. (Probably metric everywhere but in the backwards US.) Perhaps change the locale setting in Settings?

Comment: That's what I found as well, but I feel like there has to be a way to change that without relying on the user's locale. Also, changing it in iOS Settings does not change the ruler unit in the app. It only affects the Maps app.